# Servers are “coming soon”

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft of the Nintendo Switch. Recently I have been running up against a problem in which I see a message that says that servers are coming soon and are unable to be joined. Usually I can fix it if I close and reopen the application, but sometimes it persists and I have to repeat the process. Does anyone know of a way to fix this problem that isn’t so time-consuming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to check your connection to fix this. If you have a high ping, the pop-up of "Coming soon" shows up. This usually occurs when you have more than 1000 ping.

You said:

> Usually I can fix it if I close and reopen the application, but sometimes it persists and I have to repeat the process.

It's not because you are closing and reopening the app, it's your ping causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my switch. The first answer may or may not be incorrect because I had 10 thousands of ping and it was fine. The way I fixed it was logging out and back in of your Microsoft account, or as soon as you open Minecraft go onto achievements and wait a while. Then go onto servers after the achievements load.